R Unnest dataframe column with list into two columns
I have a dataframe with a list in one of the columns. The list has a code and a date. I want to transform this list into two columns, one with the code and the second one with the date.
Here is some sample data:
input=structure(list(data = c("24/05/2024", "24/05/2024", "24/05/2024","24/05/2024", "24/05/2024"), 
                     contrato = c("DI1", "DI1", "DI1","DI1", "DI1"), 
                     venc = list(c("M24", "03/06/2024"), c("N24", "01/07/2024"), c("Q24", "01/08/2024"), c("U24", "02/09/2024"), c("V24", "01/10/2024")), 
                     preco_ajuste = c("99803,97", "99024,23", "98137,14", "97296,68","96499,71")), 
             class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-5L))

and the desired output:
output=structure(list(data = c("24/05/2024", "24/05/2024", "24/05/2024", "24/05/2024", "24/05/2024"),
                      contrato = c("DI1", "DI1", "DI1", "DI1", "DI1"), 
                      venc = c("M24", "N24", "Q24", "U24", "V24"), 
                      data_vcto = c("03/06/2024", "01/07/2024", "01/08/2024", "02/09/2024", "01/10/2024"), 
                      preco_ajuste = c("99803,97","99024,23", "98137,14", "97296,68", "96499,71")), 
                 class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
                 groups = structure(list(data = "24/05/2024", .rows = structure(list(1:5), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"


venc_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(input$venc, function(x) data.frame(symbol = x[1], date = x[2])))
output <- input %>%
  select(-venc) %>%
  bind_cols(venc_df)

or
venc_df <- data.table::rbindlist(lapply(input$venc, function(x) data.frame(symbol = x[1], date = x[2])))


library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

input |>
  mutate(data_vcto = list_transpose(venc)[[2]],
         venc = list_transpose(venc)[[1]])


Use unnest_wider
library(tidyr)
input %>% 
  unnest_wider(venc, names_sep = "_") %>% 
  rename(venc = venc_1,
          data_vcto = venc_2)

# A tibble: 5 × 5
  data       contrato venc  data_vcto  preco_ajuste
  <chr>      <chr>    <chr> <chr>      <chr>       
1 24/05/2024 DI1      M24   03/06/2024 99803,97    
2 24/05/2024 DI1      N24   01/07/2024 99024,23    
3 24/05/2024 DI1      Q24   01/08/2024 98137,14    
4 24/05/2024 DI1      U24   02/09/2024 97296,68    
5 24/05/2024 DI1      V24   01/10/2024 96499,71    


Using the transpose function from data.table:
input[, c("code", "date") := transpose(venc)]

         data contrato           venc preco_ajuste   code       date
       <char>   <char>         <list>       <char> <char>     <char>
1: 24/05/2024      DI1 M24,03/06/2024     99803,97    M24 03/06/2024
2: 24/05/2024      DI1 N24,01/07/2024     99024,23    N24 01/07/2024
3: 24/05/2024      DI1 Q24,01/08/2024     98137,14    Q24 01/08/2024
4: 24/05/2024      DI1 U24,02/09/2024     97296,68    U24 02/09/2024
5: 24/05/2024      DI1 V24,01/10/2024     96499,71    V24 01/10/2024

